# Como fazer um window.scrollTo(0,0) sem animação

Tags: javascript, css, react

Tenho uma aplicação React que em determinadas situações (por causa do react-router) devo fazer um scroll até o topo da página. O problema é que na maioria dos casos o scroll deve ser animado e em algums casos específicos não.

Existe alguma forma de que eu possa forçar o scroll até o topo da página acontecer sem nenhuma animação?

> Nota: como na maioria do código deve-se usar o scroll smoth eu tenho isso definido nos arquivos globais do meu SCSS:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que *behavior* na API (`scroll()`, `scrollBy()` e `scrollTo()`) só tenha 2 valores possíveis, smooth e auto, então creio que

O mesmo vale para o CSS:

```
scroll-behavior: auto;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Aparentemente o CSS `scroll-behavior` não tem compatibilidade com Safari, [diferente da API conforme o caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_scrolltooptions), que é suportando apenas no Safari 13.1+ para MacOS (ou seja, não é suportado pelo iOS), portanto é melhor usar o API **se o objetivo for ATIVAR**, para desativar **é irrelevante** se o React usa o `scroll-behavior: smooth;`, já que provavelmente o smooth provavelmente não ocorre ou se ocorrer é algum polyfill usado (internamente, não sou experiente em React).

Então sendo como padrão o `auto` provavelmente vai depender de navegador para navegador, o que você pode experimentar é aplicar uma classe assim:

```
.behavior-auto {
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

E aplicar dinamicamente ao elemento de interesse algo como:

```
document.documentElement.classList.toggle('behavior-auto', true)
```

E para remover:

```
document.documentElement.classList.toggle('behavior-auto', false)
```

Se desejar desabilitar de qualquer "elemento filho" talvez pode tentar:

```
.behavior-auto, .behavior-auto * {
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

Mas é como eu disse, dependerá de navegador para navegador, apesar do MDN afirmar que o valor auto faz a rolagem em um único movimento.

Comment: A compatibilidade do js Options object e do Behavior css é a mesma

Comment: Olá caro @ruansenadev, poderia me esclarecer aonde eu disse que não era? Afinal eu não comentei de compatibilidade, o que eu disse é que AMBOS só possuiem o valor como AUTO, e AUTO se refere a um comportamento padrão, que pode ser até do user-agent. Compreende?

Comment: Fiz um comentário pra complementar..

Comment: @ruansenadev tem um detalhe para Safari de macOS vs Safari de iOS, resposta editada, não interfere para quem quer "desabilitar", já para quem deseja "ativar" a rolagem suave seria melhor então a API ao invés do CSS.... Claro que é preciso entender que tem comportamentos que são do sistema operacional e/ou algum polyfill como https://www.npmjs.com/package/smoothscroll-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

Chame a função com valor de [scrollOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions)

```
window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'auto'});
```

*A compatibilidade do js Options object e do Behavior css é a mesma*